# simple question of scope using a MySQL class in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This should be a no brainer, its late and i cant see what i am doing wrong:

MySQL class:

```
class MySQL
{
public $db;
private $result;

public function __construct ($host, $user, $password, $database)
{
  $this -> connectDB ($host, $user, $password, $database);
}

public function __destruct ()
{
  $this -> breakDB();
}

private function connectDB ($host, $user, $password, $database)
{
  $this -> db = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $password) or die (mysql_error());
  if (is_resource ($this -> db))
  {
    mysql_select_db ($database) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$this -> db); 
  }
}

private function breakDB()
{
  if (is_resource ($this -> db))
  {
    mysql_close ($this -> db);
    }
}
}
```

class using MySQL:

```
class Scraper {
private $urls_array = array();
private $mysql;

public function __construct ()
{
        $this -> mysql = new MySQL ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
}
private function getURLs($city=NULL,$provider=NULL) {

    /* Get all URLs to scrape */
    $result = $this -> mysql -> db = mysql_query("SELECT `xxx`,`xxx`,`xxx`, `xxx` FROM `URL` WHERE `xxx` = '1'");
   }
   }
```

The line i am having probs with is:

```
$result = $this -> mysql -> db = mysql_query("SELECT `xxx`,`xxx`,`xxx`, `xxx` FROM `URL` WHERE `xxx` = '1'");
```

I dont know how to use $mysql correctly so it sends the mysql_query to the connection i opened in the constructor? Any help apreciated THANKS!

Comment: Get rid of the (') around the 1, it's bad practice to call numeric data with a char symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to rearrange the line a bit:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `xxx`,`xxx`,`xxx`, `xxx` FROM `URL` WHERE `xxx` = '1'",
                      $this -> mysql -> db);
```

I would suggest creating a query method in your `MySQL` class though and making the `db` private.

At its most basic:

```
class MySQL {
   private $db;

   // ... as before ...

   public function query($queryText) {
       return mysql_query($queryText, $this->db);
   }
}
```

Of course, using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) might be a better idea all round.

Comment: I agree. Using mysqli or PDO is probably a better solution.

Comment: i use later on: mysql_real_escape_string(), can i use that too with mysqli, since its not listed as function? and mysqli seems really to be worth it :)

Comment: @kritop: mysqli has the same function, [mysqli::real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). You just need to call it from the object that you create: `$mysqi->real_escape_string($text)`

Comment: using: `$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");` in the constructor and later on in a function `$result = $this -> mysqli->query("SELECT `xxx` FROM `URL` WHERE `scrape` = 1");` leads to `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object` error what am i missing??

Comment: @kritop: Whenever you get that error "Call to a member function...", it means whatever variable is before one of the `->` is not an object, probably because you did not initialise it.

Answer (score 2):

You could make things a little easier on yourself by including a `query` function on the `MySQL` class you've created.  The basic jist would look like this:

```
public function query($sqlQuery)
{
     return mysql_query($sqlQuery, $this->db);
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
$result = $this->mysql->query("SELECT `xxx`,`xxx`,`xxx`, `xxx` FROM `URL` WHERE `xxx` = '1'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...", $this->mysql->db);
```

The `$db` property only holds the MySQL resource which you can optionally supply to the `mysql` functions. It would seem to make more sense if you included a `query` method in your `MySQL` class so this happens transparently and you can use `$this->mysql->query('SELECT ...')`.